# How do I make duplex printing the default in Firefox?

Tags: printing, hp, settings, duplex-printing

I have an HP Colour Laserjet 4650hdn (not sure if that matters) hooked up to my PC. It can print double sided, and I would prefer for it to print double sided. Every-time I print something from Firefox, I must tell it to print double sided. I want it to just print double sided for everything, as a default, to save paper.

I am using Ubuntu 15.10, Mate edition.

Answer (score 2):

Open your browser, and navigate to `http://localhost:631/` which is the CUPS interface

Choose

Administration ->
   Manage printers ->
     (your printer name) ->
       administration ->
         set default options

At this point you can set the duplex to be default, for either long or short sided duplex.

Comment: This doesn't affect Firefox's defaults.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason Firefox (50.0) does not respect the system defaults. To make duplex printing the default, navigate to `about:config`, then search for `duplex`. Change `print.print_duplex` to `1`, for long-edge binding.

I can't find any documentation of these options on the internet. However, from testing, `0` means single-sided, `2` means short-edge binding. I also had `print_duplex` set to `2`, if that's important.